# Unable to return a WOW6432 version of a key from 32bit application

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, registrykey

I'm trying to read a registry key from my application. It is a 32-bit process and is running on a 64-bit system(Win7 64-bit). This is my code:

```
string value64 = string.Empty;
RegistryKey localKeyRegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);    
localKey = localKey.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion");
if (localKey != null)
{
    value64 = localKey.GetValue("RegisteredOrganization").ToString();
    MessageBox.Show(value64, "value64");
}
```

On my system the value under this key(SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion) is empty, and the value under this(SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion) is "Microsoft". But the value64 in the message box is empty! Shouldn't it be "Microsoft"?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not targeting "any CPU"?

Comment: @RowlandShaw I'm going to use this in another application which has to target x86

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are specifying `RegistryView.Registry64` so it will be retrieving the value from `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion`

If you specify `RegistryView.Registry32` it will retrieve it from `SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion` instead (that is, on a 64-bit system; on a 32-bit system the WOW6432Node doesn't exist so it will just use the normal hive instead).

I think that if you specify `RegistryView.Default` it will select the hive according to the bitness of the calling process.